# Default terminal will not work in Windows

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, conemu

All options in ConEmu are enabled, but will not work (when I pressed <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> with "cmd" running cmd and not ConEmu, etc). Why?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. You have not clearly what you are trying to achieve, and the what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

1. `explorer.exe`, but not `explorer`.
2. Have you pressed `Apply` button?

Comment: "explorer.exe, but not explorer." Thank you very much. I think this will work. Like in "Run" just write "explorer" and it starts.
But it still does not work in TotalCMD x64 when I run it from the bat files, Shift+Enter или Command Lines's TotalCMD x64.
"Apply" of course press.

Comment: `totalcmd64.exe` is hooked properly on my side. Probably, you have to ask for help on their forum. May be there is something wrong with your config (especially with "noclose").